How can horizontal tension balance vertical gravity force?
I encountered this problem:

We need to find the force the hinge exerts on the object before the wire is cut. Normally, the way I do this is by balancing torques (Tnet=0) to find the tension of the wire, and then balance forces. However, the horizontal wire should not be able to exert any torque because it is parallel to the lever arm (so sin(theta) = 0).
Yet, the object is in equilibrium. I think there is something I am missing here and it has to do with the "maximum width" part, but I'm not sure.

It is a triangle of forces problem and this question is similar to: Static Equilibrium Problem with 3 Tension Forces. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your assumption that tension in the wire will produce no torque about the hinge (or the centre of mass) would be true if it acted in line with the hinge but it does not. It's offset by $y$ which is the lever arm.

If the force of gravity is acting in the y direction and is orthogonal to the x axis, then the torque due to gravity is $T_g = mg \times \Delta x = 1 *  9.81 *1.3$. The force due to the tension in the wire ($F_w$) is acting in the x direction and is orthogonal to the y axis, so the torque due to the wire is $T_w = F_w \times 0.8 \times \Delta y = F_w \times 0.8$. When the system is in equilibrium the torques are equal so $F_w = 9.81 * 1.3 / 0.8$. The force exerted by the hinge $F_h$ is the resultant of both the gravitational force and the tension force of the wire so $F_h = \sqrt{(mg)^2 + F_w^2} $ in the up and West direction.
